# How can i add 'java.awt.geom' class in android?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, awt

I am making a game in LibGDX. When i run in libgdx-desktop, than it works fine. But when i run it in libgex-android than i get this error:

```
ERROR: Could not find class 'java.awt.geom.Line2D$Float[]', referenced from method com.ia.Entity.Player.hit
```

So libgdx-android can't seem to find *line2d* class. Any idea how can i fix this? Is there way i can just add a jar file or some thing in my libgdx-android project?

I really want to use 'java.awt.geom.line2d.flot[]' in android, but if answer is no, than what can i use instead?

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaken, java.awt is not supported in android. However, I'm pretty sure libgdx has a geom class or something of that nature themselves.

Comment: Thats true, and I couldn't find a similar method in libgdx, but as its a very simple class,you could easily create it, check this too [Line2D](http://toxiclibs.org/docs/core/toxi/geom/Line2D.html) @user2570888