# AIDE - Android IDE How can I add java.awt.geom package to AIDE

Tags: java, package, aide-ide, aide

I would like to use the package java.awt.geom in my program but find that AIDE can't find it. I found this [How can i add 'java.awt.geom' class in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21075543/how-can-i-add-java-awt-geom-class-in-android) but all it says is that this package is not supported in Android.

I would like to know if there is a way to add a package to AIDE even though it's not "directly" supported?